# Interpreting coefficients in multiple logistic regression

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, interpretation, regression-coefficients

So I thought I had a handle on interpreting exponentiated coefficients from logistic regression in terms of odds and odds ratios, but I'm having more difficulty than I expected.

I'm playing with some example data I generated in R, in about the simplest possible situation.  I made 12 observations of two binary predictors and a binary response:

```
 df <- data.frame(
   x1 = factor(c("High","High","Low","Low","Low","Low","High","High","High","Low", "Low", "High"), 
   levels = c("Low", "High")), 
   x2 = factor(c("No","No","No","No","No","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes","Yes", "Yes", "No")),
   y = c(0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0))
```

If I use just one predictor, things work like I expect.

```
 xtabs(~ y + x1, df)
```

|  |  | x1 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | Low | High |
| y | 0 | 2 | 3 |
|  | 1 | 4 | 3 |

```
 mod1 <- glm(data = df, y ~ x1, "binomial")
 exp(mod1$coefficients)
```

| (Intercept) | x1High |
| --- | --- |
| 2.0 | 0.5 |

I can interpret the exponentiated intercept of 2 as the odds of `y` = 1 in the reference level of `x1` (4/2 = 2), and the exponentiated coefficient 0.5 of `x1High` as the odds ratio (3/3)/(4/2) = 0.5.  So far so good, and I can get the same sort of intelligible results if I only use `x2` as a predictor, though I omit those results in the interest of space.

But when I put both `x1` and `x2` in the model it all goes to hell, and I realize that I must not know what's going on:

```
xtabs(~ y + x1 + x2, df)
```

| x2 = No |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | x1 |  |
|  |  | Low | High |
| y | 0 | 1 | 2 |
|  | 1 | 2 | 1 |

| x2 = Yes |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | x1 |  |
|  |  | Low | High |
| y | 0 | 1 | 1 |
|  | 1 | 2 | 2 |

```
mod3 <- glm(data = df, y ~ x1 + x2, "binomial")
exp(mod3$coefficients)
```

| (Intercept) | x1High | x2Yes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.4294 | 0.4894 | 2.0433 |

Now I'm clearly off on the wrong foot, because I naively suppose that the exponentiated intercept should correspond to the odds of `y`=1 when the predictors are both at their reference levels -- when `x1` = Low and `x2` = No.  But looking at the relevant cells for that condition in the crosstabs, it would appear the odds in that condition are 2/1 = 2, not 1.4294.  Changing data the response values of data points that aren't in the reference level of either category also changes the fitted intercept, so that whole interpretation seems straight out the window.  And I also can't figure out any way of working with odds ratios that yield either of the coefficients on `x1High` or `x2Yes`.

I'd appreciate any pointers about how I can relate any odds or odds ratios that could be manually computed from the above cross-tab to any of these exponentiated logistic regression coefficients.  I started from a more complex applied problem and reduced it as far as I could to what's shown here, and I'm temporarily stuck at this point, so I thought I'd ask for some help getting unstuck.

Thanks!

P.S. I did check that my `contrasts` option for unordered factors is set to the default `contr.treatment`, like I expected.

Comment: A search finds a [huge number of posts about this topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%20logistic%20%22odds%20ratio%22).  Please review some of them, because they likely answer your questions.

Comment: Thanks, I did see one part of one of those answers that pointed me in the right direction -- I take it the weirdness I'm observing has something to do with my predictors not being orthogonal.

Comment: ...except no I just checked and my predictors happen to have exactly zero correlation, so that doesn't seem to explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are expecting your stratified cross-tabs and the covariate-adjusted logistic regression model to yield the same implied odds and odds ratios, but they do not contain the same information or make the same assumptions about the data. To reproduce the results of a stratified analysis using logistic regression, you need to include an interaction between `x1` and `x2` in the model. This makes the model saturated, meaning it will perfectly reproduce the results of the cross-tab. See below:

```
mod4 <- glm(data = df, y ~ x1*x2, "binomial")
exp(mod4$coefficients)

# (Intercept)       x1High        x2Yes x1High:x2Yes 
#        2.00         0.25         1.00         4.00
```

The odds are indeed 2 for being in the reference category of each variable. See my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/443932/computation-of-the-intercept-in-logistic-regression-model) for essentially the same question.

Comment: Yes, this is the thing that I was missing, and I'm kicking myself now that I see that I missed it, because this toy problem was actually "descended" from a real problem I was having where the saturated model couldn't be fit (at least not sensibly) because of infinite odds in one of the conditions.  So when I headed down this road I was fully aware that the saturated model was a different thing than this, and somehow along the way forgot.  Thanks for snapping it back in place.