# Logit regression for two variables

Tags: regression, logistic

I would like to know how the constant -1.694 was gotten in the image below by hand. The outcome variable is contraceptive usage, while the predictors are age group and desire. For a single predictor, I can get the constant by just dividing  the number of women using contraceptives and taking the log using one of the factor as a reference, but in this situation, I don't know how to calculate the 2 predictors. I tried to pool all the value for a factor under each variable but I am getting -1.51.

[image: Image showing the estimates for logit regression with two predictors]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Computation of the intercept in logistic regression model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/443932/computation-of-the-intercept-in-logistic-regression-model). You can't compute coefficients by hand in logistic regression unless the model is saturated. Here, they used a non-saturated model, so you can't extract the intercept from any table.